# How should I handle Azure SQL hanging when scaling up from General Purpose to Hyperscale?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm in the process of scaling up an Azure SQL database from General Purpose to Hyperscale. This has been running for more than 12 hours. When I check the "Ongoing operations" it says that it is "Scaling database performance" and "Progress: 0%".

I'm not sure if I should wait for it to complete, or click the "Cancel this operation" and try another approach. How should I handle Azure SQL hanging when scaling up from General Purpose to Hyperscale?

Comment: I suggest you raise a ticket with MS and get them to give you an update.

Comment: If you open a new tab, go to the Azure portal, does it show the database in the old state or the new state?  Can you connect to it using SSMS?

Comment: When I go to the Azure portal in a new tab, it shows the database in the old state, with a notification saying "You have 1 ongoing operation", referring to the scale up. I can connect to it using SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case was to wait for the scale up operation to complete. It took around 24 hours.